# Splunk: indexes and metrics

Tags: metrics, splunk

Could you please help me with the following question:
When creating a `metrics` and `index` in the Splunk, do you have to create a single `index` per `metrix` or you can use  many to many connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like a single event index can hold many types of events, so can a single metrics index hold many types of metrics.

If this is not the answer you seek then please clarify the question.